# Dual Boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I installed Ubuntu on a partition of my hdd while having Win10 on my ssd.
Everything worked for pretty much a month until a few min ago, when I turned on the computer and clicked on Win BM as always but it gave me this error

```
error file /efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi not found
```

And it didn't boot in Win10.
I tried a few times and it still does not work!

Also, when I booted up Ubuntu, it gave me some error screen but after a few sec it booted up as usually. I checked if everything was okay and there were no problems in Ubuntu.

I have no idea of what to do...
Help please (also, I'm a newbie with Ubuntu and dual boot so I'm really worried)

Comment: Windows updates turn fast start up back on. Check you have it off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Windows may also update UEFI resetting some settings back to defaults. Double check UEFI settings. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste in question above, the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution but if grub is on the hdd you might be able to get into Windows by booting directly to the SSD from the bios (may be F12).

Comment: Honestly, IDK where the grub is... I don't even know what the grub is lmao. But ik that Ubuntu is on sdb5 and Win10 is/was on sda1.

Comment: Try and get into the bios or the boot menu when you reboot - sometimes Esc or Del key for bios and F12 for boot menu. Look it up on Google for your hardware. Then choose to boot to your SSD rather than HDD. If that gets you into Windows then at least you have a temporary fix. Alternatively, if you can get into Ubuntu try sudo update-grub in a Terminal and see if that gets Windows back.